# Ruby Array Method array.each.upcase

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
people_names = ["Mike", "Tom", "Alison", "Jerry", "Cam"]

people_caps = people_names.each.upcase


# people_caps => ['MIKE', 'TOM', 'ALISON', 'JERRY', 'CAM']
```

I am trying to change each item in the array people_names to all caps.
I can do it with something like this:

```
people_caps = people_names.each {|name| name.upcase!}
```

but, it just also changes the people_names to all caps, but only people_caps should contain the all-caps names, people_names should stay the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code changes also `people_names`, because you call `upcase!` on all (`each`) element in that array.

If you just want to return a new array instead of changing the old one use:

```
people_caps = people_names.map { |name| name.upcase }
```

or shorter:

```
people_caps = people_names.map(&:upcase)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
people_caps = people_names.map(&:upcase)
```

Answer (score 0):

`people_caps = people_names.each {|name| name.upcase!}`

the ! will override the original people_names.

Don't use the !

You should understand what is difference between ! and without !